# CouchDB "virtual" database, that combines 2 databases into 1

Tags: couchdb

Is there feature in CouchDB to see 2 (or more) databases as 1.

For example when querying in this "virtual" databases all documents, it would show all documents from both "real" databases.

For a case when there are documents with the same _id in different databases, 2 logical resolution are possible:

- to take from the 1st database (databases order is specified)
- to take document with bigger revision number

Both resolution would be OK. I just need it to be predictable.

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is no. The only thing that _might_ work is to write a view with a map function that can query the other database. I know I've done this in Mongo. I wrote a map function in Mongo that made a query to another database. But I seriously doubt this can be done in Couch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature, so you'll have to code it yourself.